# Jackson Deserialize Key/Value List into List<Class>

Tags: java, jackson, pojo

I have a response from web service call like this

```
// other key/values
properties: {
   1000:true
   2000:false
   2939:true
   ...
}
// other key/values
```

I want to deserialize it to a POJO List which is

```java
public class Service implements Serializable {
   private Integer id;
   private Boolean readOnly;
   ...
}
```

So far i have tried

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
user.setServices(mapper.convertValue(response.getProperties(), Service.class));
```

But it doesn't convert map directly to the List. How do i achieve this? Here are the details:

Where response.getProperties() returns

```java
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<Integer, Boolean> getProperties() {
    return properties;
}
```

And user.setServices

```java
public void setServices(List<Service> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }
```

Comment: Are the ids unique

Comment: yes they are  unique

Comment: `{"roperties":{"1000":true,"2000":false,"2939":true}}` this is the json structure ryt.

Comment: yes it is, without double quotes

Comment: that is not a valid json

Comment: This is what i get from a web service call. Still i have to convert it. Do you have any idea?